# Prove that the parabloas are mutually perpendicular.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given that two parabolas have the same focus with their axes of symmetry in opposite directions. Then I have to prove that the two intersect at right angles. As I think, because the axes are oppositely directed, the directrices must be rotated by an angle $π$ . So let their equations be $x+y+c=0$ and $x-y+c=0$. Let the common focus of the two parabolas be, for simplicity, the origin $(0,0)$. Then the two parabolas are:
$$F(x,y):=x^2+y^2-(x+y+c)^2=0$$
$$G(x,y):=x^2+y^2-(x-y+c)^2=0$$
Hence , the angle between the two parabolas comes out to be:
$$atan \frac {F_xG_y - F_yG_x}{F_xG_x + F_yG_y}$$
$$= atan \frac {2c(c+x)}{x^2+2cx+y^2}$$
Where am I getting wrong?
The subscripts stand for partial differentials.

Comment: What do you mean by "axes ... in *opposite direction*"?

Comment: @user10354138, this means that the axes of symmetry of the two parabolas are antiparallel.

Comment: By antiparallel is meant perpendicular?

Comment: @coffeemath, of course not. Antiparallel is parallel but rotated by 180 deg.

Comment: But $x\pm y-c=0$ are perpendicular, not (anti-)parallel.

Comment: So how to make antiparallel lines.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the parabolas are congruent. I don’t see that anywhere in the initial problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the parabolae are conguent**: Suppose the directrices are $y=c$ and $y=-c$.  Then the equations of the parabolae are:
$$\Gamma_\pm:=(x^2+y^2=(y\mp c)^2)=(x^2\pm2yc-c^2=0)$$
They intersect at $(\pm c,0)$ and it is easy to see their tangents have slope $\pm 1$ there.

**If the parabolae are not congruent**: the directrices $y=c_i$, $i=1,2$ gives
$$
\Gamma_i:=(x^2+2yc_i-c_i^2=0)
$$
so $y=\frac12(c_1+c_2)$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{-c_1c_2}$ (in particular, $c_1c_2<0$).  Differentiating gives the slopes are $-\frac{c_i}{x}$ and so multiplies to $-1$.

Comment: Oops, yes that is indeed not given.  Corrected.